FormGroup in Angular Reactive Form Returning undefined When Accessed Even though Form is initialize
I’m working on an Angular project where I have a reactive form named memberForm, which includes a nested FormGroup called MemberInstallmentDetails. Even though I’ve defined and initialized MemberInstallmentDetails, when I try to access it using this.memberForm.get('MemberInstallmentDetails'), it returns undefined.
this.memberForm = this.fb.group({
  // other form controls...
  MemberInstallmentDetails: this.fb.group({
    MarlaID: [''],
    PlanID: [''],
    SocietyID: [''],
    MemberID: [this.memberID],
    InstallmentPlans: this.fb.array([])
  })
});


const gr = this.memberForm.get('MemberInstallmentDetails') as FormGroup;
console.log(gr); // This logs `undefined`


I'm new to agnular so don't have the idea what should i do

Where are you initializing this memberForm? inside ngOnInit?
